# What gcc version do I need?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, gcc

I have installed ns-2.28 on ubuntu 12.04. My kernel version is 3.2.0-29-generic-pae.
What gcc version matches my ns-2.28 & 3.2.0-29-generic-pae?

Answer (score 2):

That is supposed to be done by Ubuntu Maintainers in their repository unless you build it from sources (a bad practice to new bees which I presume you did not do). So just install the package needed, that is:

```
sudo apt-get install  build-essential
```